# How to display words with accent

Tags: php, json

when i try to encode a word with accent like `Sous-Préfecture` like this:

```
$libelle=utf8_encode('Sous-Préfecture');
echo json_encode($libelle);
```

i got:

```
Sous-Pr\u00e9fecture
```

Is there any way to show the accent in that kind of words?

Comment: Please bear with me if you already know that but JSON is a format for automated data exchange. How accents look like is not relevant as long as it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo json_encode(utf8_decode($libelle));
```

Comment: Now it's replacing the accent caracter by a `?` like this `Sous-Pr?fecture`